# Gmaps4rails marker picture doesnt show instead a string "undefined" appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I was trying to generate several maps dynamically everything went fine but the marker picture doesnt show instead a string "undefined" appears still in the right place. Here's the code.

hash method implemented in the object model

```
    def hash
    hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(location) do |loc, marker|
        marker.lat loc.latitude 
        marker.lng loc.longitude 
        marker.picture ({
            :url => "http://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png", 
            :width => 32, 
            :height => 32
            })
    end
    hash
end
```

coffeescript code

```
class RichMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker 
 create_marker: ->
 options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
 @serviceObject = new RichMarker options 

 rich_marker_options: ->
  marker = document.createElement("div")
  marker.setAttribute 'class', 'marker_container'
  marker.innerHTML = @args.marker
  { content: marker }

@buildMap = (markers, id)->

 handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} }
 handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: id} }, ->
  markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
  handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

And included the script call in the view

```
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            $(window).on('load', function(){
                buildMap(<%= raw hash.to_json%>,<%=entity.id%>);
            });
    </SCRIPT>
```

everything is fine except for the marker picture and I can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

javascript code:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
 markers = handler.addMarkers([
 {
  "lat": 0,
  "lng": 0,
  "picture": {
    "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
    "width":  36,
    "height": 36
  },
  "infowindow": "hello!"
}
 ]);
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

buildMap function test version:

```
@buildMap = ->  
 handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} } 

 handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
 markers = handler.addMarkers([
  {"lat": 0, "lng": 0, 'picture':{'url':'http://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png'}}
 ])
 handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
 handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Comment: Whats the generated json for markers?

Comment: the picture url appears there also its width and height along with latitude and longitude.

Comment: still... can you provide it please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply  "[{\"lat\":30.0502326,\"lng\":31.3245312,\"picture\":{\"url\":\"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png\",\"width\":32,\"height\":32}}]" this the return value of entity.hash.to_json

Comment: Well, when I tried to use the javascript code provided on github in the documentation everything worked fine, but I cant figure out how could I use this code to generate multiple maps dynamically so I went with the buildMap coffeescript. I will edit the post and add the javascript code I mentioned above.

Comment: What is you prepend `http://` to the pic url?

Comment: https:// , tried changing it to http:// still doesn't work

Comment: cant tell, it works with your provided json: http://plnkr.co/edit/ThWoumBhwyH7kTzfOHck?p=preview

Comment: but... I wonder if you really have an issue with marker, do you have div with ids matching all 
your entity.id

Comment: I believe there's a problem with the RichMarkerBuilder, I will try to figure it. Thanks alot for your support.

Comment: the ids are matching with the entity.id, that's why the marker appears at the right lat and lng but instead of the marker picture, "undefined" appears. I tried generating several maps for several entities each with different address and the marker is always at the right place. I think the problem is with the richmarker for some reason it cant pull out the picture hash. Could you please try using the richmarkerbuilder and check if everything is ok?

Comment: I started toying with the richmarker builder and changed the buildMap function to test it, I will add the new version in the post. The output is the same although I directly defined the picture inside the buildMap function itself.

Comment: You should create a plunkr, start from the one I posted above

Comment: Thanks alot mate, how can I upvote you?

Comment: Update other answers of mine if you like:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As apneadiving suggested:
At last, I found a solution. It's ugly but still working. I redefined buildMap function without using the RichMarkerBuilder

```
function buildMap(handler,id) {
    var lat = handler[0]['lat'];
    var lng = handler[0]['lng'];
    var picture = handler[0][picture];
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: id}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers([
        {
          "lat": lat,
          "lng": lng,
          "picture": picture,
        }
      ]);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
    });
  };
```

The function takes 4 args, The handler which is the return value of (raw entity.hash.to_json), the id of the entity to create a new map for each entity, the lng and lat are the longitude and latitude of the location of the entity. I couldn't figure out how to pull those from the passed handler object.

PS: apneadiving suggested this solution, the code is pretty ugly due to my limited js skills though.

Comment: Not sure why you pass handler as arg

Comment: Neither do I actually, but I tried removing the handler from args which is the json of the marker and I got an error. Any help to clean this mess would be very appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated the code to a version which I believe is a bit cleaner